# Yourkit Java Profiling for JVM - Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, oracle, ubuntu-14.04

**Question:** What I have Done:

1. I download the trial version (**https://www.yourkit.com/download/** ) YourKit Java Profiler for **Linux** and testing in my AWS Instance.

   2. I am trying to **Enabling profiling manually** by the following steps,

   (-agentpath:/home/yourkit/yjp-2015-build-15078/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so)

   3. I am getting the following error,

   **ERROR: Waht I am getting:**

> [YourKit Java Profiler 2015 build 15078] Cannot create log file:
>   /home/ubuntu/.yjp/log/java-1884.log
>         To specify alternate log directory use startup option 'logdir'
>       15078 0.000: Command line:
>         java
>         -agentpath:/home/yourkit/yjp-2015-build-15078/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so
>       15078 0.000: Executable: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
>       15078 0.000: uname:
>         sysname: Linux
>         release: 3.13.0-48-generic
>         version: #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
>         machine: x86_64
>       15078 0.000: Linux; fast_thread_cpu_time=1; 64-bit process
>       15078 0.001: hid: 36022997176V9ZXX3UXV5UWZ513Z98931W 64-bit machine
>       15078 0.001: Today is 20151201
>       15078 0.001: full_build_stamp: 15078 201511161426
>       15078 0.001: Agent library path: /home/yourkit/yjp-2015-build-15078/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so
>       15078 0.001: Agent_OnLoad: orig_options=
>         full_options=
>       15078 0.001: phase: 1
>       15078 0.001: jvmtiVersion: 30010203
>       15078 0.001: vendor: Oracle Corporation
>       15078 0.001: version: 25.66-b17
>       15078 0.001: info: mixed mode, sharing
>       15078 0.001: Java 8 detected
>       15078 0.001: session_id: 8093167346477 (1448960813,1884)
>       15078 0.003: line_method: 1
>       15078 0.008: Reusing existing jar file: /tmp/yjp201511161426.jar
>       15078 0.008: JVMTI 30010203; 25.66-b17; Oracle Corporation; mixed mode, sharing; JR=0; I=0
>       15078 0.025: Successfully registered probe classes: 120
>         Registered: .AWTEvents$EventQueue_dispatchEvent_Probe
>         Registered: .AgentLoadingSupport$JBoss
>         Registered: .AgentLoadingSupport$OSGi1
>         Registered: .AgentLoadingSupport$OSGi2
>         Registered: .AgentLoadingSupport$OSGi3
>         Registered: .Databases$Connection_close_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Connection_createStatement_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Connection_prepareStatement_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$DataSource_getConnection_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$DataSource_setName_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$DriverManager_getConnection_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Driver_connect_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$InitialContext_lookup_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$PooledConnection_getConnection_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$PreparedStatement_addBatch_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$PreparedStatement_clearBatch_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$PreparedStatement_execute_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Statement_addBatch_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Statement_clearBatch_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Statement_close_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Statement_executeBatch_Probe
>         Registered: .Databases$Statement_execute_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$Connection_close_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$Connection_createStatement_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$Connection_prepareStatement_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$DataSource_getConnection_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$DriverManager_getConnection_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$Driver_connect_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$PooledConnection_getConnection_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$PreparedStatement_execute_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$Statement_close_Probe
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$Statement_execute_Probe1
>         Registered: .DatabasesLW$Statement_execute_Probe2
>         Registered: .Files$FileChannel_read_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileChannel_write_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileInputStream_close_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileInputStream_open_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileInputStream_readBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileInputStream_read_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileOutputStream_close_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileOutputStream_open_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileOutputStream_writeBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$FileOutputStream_write_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$GetChannel_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$RandomAccessFile_close_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$RandomAccessFile_open_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$RandomAccessFile_readBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$RandomAccessFile_read_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$RandomAccessFile_writeBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .Files$RandomAccessFile_write_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileChannelsTelemetry$FileChannel_read_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileChannelsTelemetry$FileChannel_write_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileChannelsTelemetry$GetChannel_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileInputStream_close_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileInputStream_open_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileInputStream_readBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileInputStream_read_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileOutputStream_close_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileOutputStream_open_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileOutputStream_writeBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$FileStreamsTelemetry$FileOutputStream_write_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$RandomAccessFilesTelemetry$RandomAccessFile_close_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$RandomAccessFilesTelemetry$RandomAccessFile_open_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$RandomAccessFilesTelemetry$RandomAccessFile_readBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$RandomAccessFilesTelemetry$RandomAccessFile_read_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$RandomAccessFilesTelemetry$RandomAccessFile_writeBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .FilesLW$RandomAccessFilesTelemetry$RandomAccessFile_write_Probe
>         Registered: .JNDI$DirContext_1
>         Registered: .JNDI$DirContext_2
>         Registered: .JNDI$NamingContext_1
>         Registered: .JNDI$NamingContext_2
>         Registered: .JUnitTests$Old_Run_Probe
>         Registered: .JUnitTests$Old_SetUp_Probe
>         Registered: .JUnitTests$Old_TearDown_Probe
>         Registered: .JUnitTests$Run_Probe
>         Registered: .JUnitTests$SetUp_Probe
>         Registered: .JUnitTests$TearDown_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$FileOutputStream_writeBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$FileOutputStream_write_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$InputStream_readBytes_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$InputStream_read_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$ProcessImpl_getErrorStream_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$ProcessImpl_getInputStream_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$ProcessImpl_getOutputStream_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$ProcessImpl_start_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$ProcessImpl_waitFor_Probe
>         Registered: .Processes$UnixProcess_waitForProcessExit_Probe
>         Registered: .Servlets$Filter_doFilter_Probe
>         Registered: .Servlets$HttpJspPage_jspService_Probe
>         Registered: .Servlets$Servlet_service_Probe
>         Registered: .ServletsLW$Filter_doFilter_Probe
>         Registered: .ServletsLW$HttpJspPage_jspService_Probe
>         Registered: .ServletsLW$Servlet_service_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$ServerSocketChannel_accept_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$ServerSocket_accept_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$SocketChannel_close_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$SocketChannel_connect_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$SocketChannel_read_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$SocketChannel_write_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$SocketInputStream_read_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$SocketOutputStream_write_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$Socket_close_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$Socket_connect_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$Socket_getInputStream_Probe
>         Registered: .Sockets$Socket_getOutputStream_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$ServerSocketChannel_accept_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$ServerSocket_accept_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$SocketChannel_close_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$SocketChannel_connect_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$SocketChannel_read_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$SocketChannel_write_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$SocketInputStream_read_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$SocketOutputStream_write_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$Socket_close_Probe
>         Registered: .SocketsLW$Socket_connect_Probe
>         Registered: .TestNG$Test_Probe
>         Registered: .Threads$Thread_constructor_Probe
>         Registered: .Threads$Thread_run_Probe
>         Registered: .Threads$Thread_setName_Probe
>         Registered: .Threads$Thread_start_Probe
>       15078 0.089: agentStart: 1
>       15078 0.089: agentStart: 2
>       15078 0.090: agentStart: OK
>       15078 0.106: tracing=off: large method: 3945 sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets$Aliases.init(java.lang.Object[])
>       15078 0.211: agentInit: 1
>       15078 0.212: agentInit: Core loaded
>       15078 0.216: setTriggers:
>       15078 0.277: setTriggers: to unregister: 0
>       15078 0.277: setTriggers: method listeners to register: 0
>       15078 0.277: setTriggers: OK
>       15078 0.277: ourUnsafe: true
>       15078 0.277: shmem 42341490: OK
>       15078 0.277: shmem 4234148E: OK
>       15078 0.298: Profiler agent is listening on port 10001
>       15078 0.301: *** HINT ***: To get profiling results, connect to the application from the profiler UI
>       15078 0.301: agentInit: Core.init() called
>       15078 0.301: agentInit: OK
>       15078 0.302: startProfiling: 1
>       15078 0.302: startProfiling: OK
>       15078 0.302: socket timeout: 30000
>       15078 0.358: SP: pin java.io.FileNotFoundException
>       15078 0.358: SP: pin java.security.PrivilegedActionException
>       15078 0.399: SP: pin java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
>       15078 0.432: tracing=off: large method: 4108 sun.text.resources.FormatData.getContents()
>       15078 0.455: SP: pin java.lang.NoSuchFieldException
>       15078 0.473: tracing=off: large method: 8578 sun.util.resources.CurrencyNames.getContents()
>       Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>                  (to execute a class)
>          or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>                  (to execute a jar file)
>       where options include:
>           -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
>           -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
>           -server       to select the "server" VM
>                         The default VM is server,
>                         because you are running on a server-class machine.
>           -cp 
>           -classpath 
>                         A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
>                         and ZIP archives to search for class files.
>           -D=
>                         set a system property
>           -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
>                         enable verbose output
>           -version      print product version and exit
>           -version:
>                         Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
>                         in a future release.
>                         require the specified version to run
>           -showversion  print product version and continue
>           -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
>                         Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
>                         in a future release.
>                         include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
>           -? -help      print this help message
>           -X            print help on non-standard options
>           -ea[:...|:]
>           -enableassertions[:...|:]
>                         enable assertions with specified granularity
>           -da[:...|:]
>           -disableassertions[:...|:]
>                         disable assertions with specified granularity
>           -esa | -enablesystemassertions
>                         enable system assertions
>           -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
>                         disable system assertions
>           -agentlib:[=]
>                         load native agent library , e.g. -agentlib:hprof
>                         see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
>           -agentpath:[=]
>                         load native agent library by full pathname
>           -javaagent:[=]
>                         load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
>           -splash:
>                         show splash screen with specified image
>       See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html
>   for more details.
>       15078 0.492: vmDeath: 1
>       15078 0.492: vmDeath: 2
>       15078 0.492: vmDeath: 3
>       15078 0.492: vmDeath: 4
>       15078 0.492: vmDeath: OK

**Questions:**

```
1. Need Installation steps Yourkit Java Profiling for JVM - Ubuntu.

2. How to connect through remote.
```

Answer (score 1):

I work everyday on YourKitJavaProfiler, and it's running perfectly on my debian OS.

### 1. Read the ouput

> [YourKit Java Profiler 2015 build 15078] Cannot create log file: /home/ubuntu/.yjp/log/java-1884.log To specify alternate log directory use startup option 'logdir'

According to your log files, il looks like the user whose running the java process does not have access write on your `/home/ubuntu/.yjp/log/` folder.

Grant access to your user, restart your application and check if it works.

### 2. How to monitor a remote application

For remote profiling, start your JVM with the profiler agent as your did localy on your AWS server and when the remote application is running, connect to it from the profiler UI to perform profiling.

In some cases you will have to unable manual profiling by running a server agent. See the `Enabling profiling manually` [documentation page](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/agent.jsp).